# Find $x_{n}=\frac{5(-1)^{n}-3}{4(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}n+2}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis

Given sequence $x_{n}=\frac{10(-1)^{n}*n-4}{4(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}n+2}, n\in \mathbb{N}$. How to find all of the subsequential limits of this sequence?

Comment: Doesn't the sequence converge to $0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

The answer is that the elements

$$x_{n}=\frac{5 (-1)^n-3}{4 n (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor }+2}, n=0,1,2,...\tag{1}$$

create 4 different sequences, and all of them have the limit $0$ for $n\to\infty$.

But the problem deserves a more thorough study.

**Revealing the 4 sequences**

The first 10 terms of the sequence are

$$\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{n=10} = \left\{1,-\frac{4}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{9},-\frac{4}{11},-\frac{1}{11},\frac{4}{13},\frac{1}{17},-\frac{4}{19},-\frac{1}{19}\right\}\tag{2}$$

These look rather confusing, a pattern would be hard to guess.

Inspecting the formula for $x_{n}$ we focus on the terms $c(n)=(-1)^{n}$ and $d(n) = (-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}$ and study the possible parities of the index $n$.

$n$ can be even or odd, for $n=2m$ we have $c(2m)=+1$ and $d(2m)=(-1)^{m}$, and for $n=2m-1$ we have $c(n)=(-1)$ and again $d(2m-1)=(-1)^{m}$. Now in $m$ in turn can be even or odd, leading to 4 cases for $n$.

These cases can be parametrized by letting $n=4m+k$, with $m=0,1,2,...$ and $k=0,1,2,3$.

Inserting this we find

$$x_{n} =x_{m,k}:= \frac{5(-1)^{4 m+k}-3}{4(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{4m+k}{2} \right \rfloor}(4m+k+2)}=\frac{5(-1)^{k}-3}{4(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right \rfloor}(4m+k+2)}\tag{3}$$

explcitly we find for the four sequences

$$\begin{align}\{x_{m,k}\}_{k=0}^{3}
& =\left\{\frac{1}{8 m+1},-\frac{4}{8 m+3},\frac{1}{-8 m-3},\frac{4}{8 m+5}\right\}, m=0,1,2,...\\
& =\left\{\frac{1}{2 n+1}|_{n=4m},\frac{-4}{2n+1}|_{n=4m+1},
\frac{-1}{2n-1}|_{n=4m+2},\frac{-4}{2n-1}|_{n=4m+3}\right\}, \\& n=0,1,2,...
\end{align}\tag{4}$$

Obvioulsly, the limit for $m\to\infty$ is zero for all sequences.

**Plot of the 4 sequences**

[image]

**Generating function**

The generating function of the sequence $x_{n}$ is defined as

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n x_{n}\tag{5}$$

Taking care of the four sequences we have here

$\begin{align}
g(z) =& \sum _{k=0}^3 \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } x(k+4 m) z^{k+4 m}\right)\\
& =\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{8},1;\frac{9}{8};z^4\right)\\
& -\frac{4}{3} z \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{8},1;\frac{11}{8};z^4\right)\\
& -\frac{1}{3} z^2 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{8},1;\frac{11}{8};z^4\right)\\
& +\frac{4}{5} z^3 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{5}{8},1;\frac{13}{8};z^4\right)
\end{align}\tag{6}$

here $\, _2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ is a hypergeometric function.

Expanding $g(z)$ in a power series around $z=0$ gives

$$g(z) = 1-\frac{4}{3}z-\frac{1}{3}z^2+\frac{4}{5}z^3+\frac{1}{9}z^4-\frac{4}{11}z^5-\frac{1}{11}z^6+\frac{4}{13}z^7+\frac{1}{17}z^8-\frac{4}{19}z^9-\frac{1}{19}z^{10}+...$$

and reproduces the sequence $(2)$.

Here is a plot of the generating function

[image]

The plot shows that $g(z)$ is finite in the range $-1\le z \le 1$

The boundary values which are at the same time the values of the series  and the alternating series of the $x_{n}$, respectively, are

$$\begin{align}
g_1 = g(z=1) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_{n}\\
& =\frac{1}{8} \left(5 \pi +2 \sqrt{2} \left(\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-2 \pi \right)\right)\\
&\simeq 0.0536666
\end{align}\tag{7a}$$

$$\begin{align}
g_{-1}=g(z=-1) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x_{n}\\
& = \frac{1}{8} \left(2 \sqrt{2} \left(2 \pi +\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-3 \pi \right)\\
& \simeq 1.35496
\end{align}\tag{7b}$$

Finally, we can also calculate the integral over the generating function

$$i= \int_{-1}^{1} g(z)\,dz = \frac{\pi }{3 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\log (2)}{3}+\frac{\log \left(17+12 \sqrt{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2}} \simeq 1.8025\tag{8}$$

Summarising, we have discovered several interesting relations and rather smooth functions and unexpected explicit results from the bizarre looking sequence term $x_{n}$.